# How to set the dojoConfig parameter in dojoeditor based on a hidden variable value

Tags: javascript, dojo, rich-text-editor

I am new to dojo(infact coding) and am struggling with setting the locale on the dojo editor. I have a scenario where in 
**JSP1:** language value is input and the value is submitted as a hidden variable
**JSP2:** DOJo editor is displayed based on the language.I would like to set the locale of the  dojo editor. I am trying to retrieve the hidden variable value but the editor always shows with "en" locale.  I have done "View Source" on the page and the hidden variable is populated with the correct parameter.

```
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    var editorLang = '';
    var currentLocale = '${param.selected_lang}' ; //is an issue , 
                                                 //cant see the lang getting retrieved
    document.write(currentLocale);
    if(currentLocale=='fr'){
               editorLang = 'fr';
         }else if(currentLocale=='en'){
              editorLang = 'en-us';
        }        
    var dojoConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        isDebug: false,
        locale: editorLang

    };
  </script>
   <style type="text/css">
    @import "../script/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/dojo/dojo/dojo.js">   
</script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
 dojo.require("dijit.Editor");
      dojo.require("dijit._editor.plugins.LinkDialog");    
      dojo.require("dijit._editor.plugins.TextColor");
      dojo.require("dijit._editor.plugins.AlwaysShowToolbar");   
      dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    </script>
    <script>
  dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
  var editorVal = document.getElementById("editorContents").value;
  var lang = document.getElementById("selected_lang").value; 
  alert(lang);                                              *//here its fine
                                                                 //can see the lang*
  var defaultVal = document.getElementById("DeafultValue").value;   
       var editor1 = dijit.byId("editor");

  editor1.onLoadDeferred.addCallback(function(){
         editor1.set("value", defaultVal );     
         });
    }); 



  </script> 
 <head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it  by  moving the dojo related stuff inside the body (initially was in )